# No provider for dynamically created component after migration to micro-fronts structure

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, micro-frontend

The stack is way too complicated to recreate it, so forgive me in advance and ask me for further information.

The Angular app has the following structure:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:[
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    // These two components share common state
    // in ServiceFoo.
    // ParentComponent will call the ModalService
    // to render the DynamicallyRenderedComponent
    // into a modal.
    ParentComponent,
    DynamicallyRenderedComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ServiceFoo
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule {} // This module is lazy loaded

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

@NgModule({
  imports:[
    OverlayModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    // Hosts a component using ViewContainerRef
    // and ComponentFactoryResolver
    HostComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    // Displays the modal (HostComponent) and passes in 
    // the component we want to display in the modal
    ModalService
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

// Of-course at the top there is the AppModule that includes all
```

Now this setup has been working perfectly until I moved the client under a React application, which is a container app that hosts other apps (micro-frontends). The container app will load NG client's scripts and bootstrap the app in the React app.

Everything is working fine except the dependency injection for the dynamically rendered components. They stopped having access to the services declared in their module and thus throw the infamous error:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2560 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ServiceFoo -> ServiceFoo -> ServiceFoo]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ServiceFoo!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:1013)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11122)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11122)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11122)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:24243)
    at Object.get (core.js:22142)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:4079)
    at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:14651)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.ParentComponent [as factory] (ɵfac.js? [sm]:1)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:4184)
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: When checking NgModuleRef, anywhere in my FeatureModule, it says that my instance is the AppModule. For some reason it sets the wrong reference or it loses it along the way. Therefore the ComponentFactoryResolver cannot provide the correct injectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the way I did the bootstrap for the Angular application

Wrong approach:

```js
import {createCustomElement} from '@angular/elements';

@NgModule({....})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private injector: Injector, private router: Router) {
    const micro = createCustomElement(MainComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define(appContainer, micro);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap(): void {
    this.router.initialNavigation();
  }
}
```

Correct approach:

```js
@NgModule({....})
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef): void {
    this.router.initialNavigation();
    appRef.bootstrap(MainComponent, appContainer);
  }
}
```

*`appContainer` is the custom element that will host the micro-front